# Elasticsearch Shield role not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to set up a DLS role in shield as

```
123user:
   indices:
    - names: 'myIndex'
      privileges: 
        - read
      query:
        term:
         header.code: '123'
```

and i added this user as

```
esusers useradd 123guy -p 123pass -r 123user
```

now when i logged in to Kibana, by default it went to the Discover view and i got an authentication exception. Since i have other indices as well, other than `myIndex`, and one of those is set as default index for Kibana, i think thats what caused the exception. so i made a slight change to the role as

```
123user:
   indices:
    - names: '*'
      privileges: 
        - read
      query:
        term:
         header.code: '123'
```

but now when i log into Kibana, i do not see anything. I am able to log in but i get a blank screen for all of the tabs (Discover,Dashboard,Settings and Visualize)

how should i set up this role correctly. I tried to add this role via a post command but then i got

```
esusers list
123guy        : 123user*
es_admin       : admin
kibana         : kibana4_server

[*]   An unknown role. Please check [/path/to/roles.yml] to see available roles
```

so i added the role explicitly in the roles.yml file. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: **" i think thats what caused the exception"** what was the exception? And what Shield and ES version is this?

Comment: es 2.3.1. the exception said that the user 123guy is unauthorized.

Answer (score 0):

Your role was not specified correctly in roles.yml file and also make sure that Indentation are correct. 
For reference check this blog
http://blog.trifork.com/2015/03/05/shield-your-kibana-dashboards/